# Dashboard for IRobot Create 2

Tags: control, irobot-create

In case anyone is interested, I build a dashboard for the icreate 2.(http://blog.mindfront.net/2017/06/roomba-dashboard-cli-dashboard-for.html)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Deepak. On Stack exchange *questions* must ask a question. StackExchange isn't a discussion forum, it's a place to ask questions and get answers. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and read [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and [How not to be a spammer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). If you wish to discuss Robotics in general you can use [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is overt self promotion.

Comment: Is there a place to discuss irobot's create 2 platform? This forum seems overly restrictive on what can be discussed. The point of sharing something is so others might be able to build on top of it (not self promotion).

Comment: Hi Deepak, Stack exchange is not a discussion forum. We provide for a limited amount of discussion, to help people improve their questions and answers, but primarily our community is based around the idea of asking questions and getting the best answer possible. As I said, at 20 reputation you will be able to use [chat]. You only need one answer upvote or two question upvotes to get 21 reputation, so you aren't far off,  but sadly [chat] is often not very active.